# Grails+Jquery-ui - integration issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, grails, grails-2.0

I have been trying to use grails with the jquery-ui plug-in, I have created a simple controller along with a gsp page that uses a datepicker, I have not been able to get the date picker to show a list of dates. I have read the plug in documentation + articles on forums etc. but have not found a resolution.

Plug in documentation - http://grails.org/plugin/jquery-ui

**Dev environment = grails 2.2.0, JDK 7, GGTS latest version**

Any pointers to getting this working would be great.

(I have tried copying/renaming files in web app/other folders but have not been successful)

Steps 
1. Created a new grails project

1. installed the jQuery-ui plug in
2. Created a controller and gsp page - per the documentation
3. When I navigate to the page it gives me the following error

   **ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /plugins/jquery-ui-1.8.24/jquery-ui/themes/darkness/jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom.css 
   | Error ERROR [/Test2].[default]  - Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/Test2] threw exception 
   Message: It looks like you are missing some calls to the r:layoutR**

The correct solution on 23-jan-13 that worked in my environment as described in the original post is shown below, I found the code posted on the grails website does not necessarily work as is - hence this edit. (if anyone has any edits do let me know directly)

GSP Code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simple GSP page</title>
        <g:javascript library="jquery" />
        <g:javascript library="jquery-ui"/>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function() { 
               $("#datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd'}); }) 
        </script>
 <r:layoutResources/>   
 </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p> Between <input type="text" id="datepicker"> </p>        
        </div>
      <r:layoutResources/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Controller code:

```
def testDatePicker = { 
}
```

Comment: Did you find out how to switch themes in your solution?

Comment: At this point I am just sticking with the default theme (UI lightness)  - Next I plan to design my own theme using the themeroller and then link it to the application, If you want I can ping you when I am done with that.

Comment: I will be nice, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Note - I incorrectly edited my original question along with providing the answer, the original question also has the solution description.***

I finally was successful integrating jquery-ui and grails, faced some issue which allow the solution to runs. Steps.

1. Create new **Grails** project (my environment grails 2.2.0, JDK 7, GGTS latest version)
2. Install **jquery-ui** plug-in, edit *BuildConfig* add **runtime ":jquery-ui:1.8.24"**.
3. Create a controller and gsp page, using grails

**GSP Page content**

```
 <html>
    <head>

    <title>Simple GSP page</title>
    <g:javascript library="jquery" />
    <g:javascript library="jquery-ui"/>

    <r:layoutResources/>   

    <script type="text/javascript">

       $(document).ready(function() { 
           $("#datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd'}); }) 
    </script>


     </head>
        <body>
            <div>
                <p> Between <input type="text" id="datepicker"> </p>        
            </div>
          <r:layoutResources/>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**Controller code:**

```
    def testDatePicker = { 
    }
```

4. Run the solution in grails, navigate to the date picker on your page, it should show you the sleek date picker

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the Resource framework? If yes, you should use the `jquery-ui` module like this:

```
<r:require module="jquery-ui"/>
```

Documentation on [jquery-ui and resource framework](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-resources/guide/1.%20Overview.html#1.1.2%20Install%20jQuery%20UI%20and%20Blueprint%20plugins).

Comment: I got the same error. Maybe the issue is that the URL being composed by grails starts with /plugins/jquery-ui-... which really does not refer to the local c:/...local path to the Java script file that means it will not refer to a proper CSS/js file. I know the key to this maybe the resources framework...which I havent figured out...any tips pointers are appreciated.

Comment: I finally got it to work - see edits made on the original post

Comment: Yep tweaking the sequence the code has to exist in took time to get to. While doing all this - I ended up learning how to use the resources library, which is pretty useful. for some reason adding the <require, did not work for my solution, but it should per the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add following line for plugin.

```
plugins {    
        runtime ":jquery:1.8.3"
        compile ":jquery-ui:1.8.24"
    }
```

And add the following line on which gsp page you use Jquery UI.

```
< head>
     < g:javascript library="jquery" />
     < r:require modules="jquery-ui"/>
     < r:script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
               your code...
        });
     < /r:script>
< /head>
```