# JQuery Validation UI plugin not including qTip resources

Tags: validation, grails, grails-plugin, qtip

I'm using the latest version of **JQuery Validation UI Plugin** which is 1.4 and using grails 2.1.0.

I cannot get it to display the qTips correctly as it appears to not include the files *jquery.qtip.pack.js* & *jquery.qtip.css* (firebug console shows they are not pulled in).

I see in the plugins *JqueryValidationUiResources.groovy* it has the following:

```
modules = {
    'jquery-validation-ui' {
        dependsOn 'jquery, jquery-validate'
        resource id:"validation-methods", url:[plugin:'jqueryValidationUi', dir:'js/jquery-validation-ui', file:'grails-validation-methods.js']
    }

    'jquery-validation-ui-qtip' {
        dependsOn 'jquery-validation-ui'
        resource id:"qtip", url:[plugin:'jqueryValidationUi', dir:'js/qTip', file:'jquery.qtip.pack.js']
        resource id:"qtip-theme", url:[plugin:'jqueryValidationUi', dir:'css/qTip', file:'jquery.qtip.css']
    }    
}
```

My Config.groovy:

```
jqueryValidationUi {

    errorClass = 'error'
    validClass = 'valid'
    onsubmit = true
    renderErrorsOnTop = false
    qtip = true

    qTip {
        packed = true
      classes = 'ui-tooltip-red ui-tooltip-shadow ui-tooltip-rounded'
    }

    ....
}
```

This is how I include the resources in page as per [documentation](http://limcheekin.github.com/jquery-validation-ui/docs/guide/overview.html).

```
<head>
    ...
    <r:require modules="jquery-validation-ui" />
    ...
</head>

<body>
    ...
    <jqvalui:renderValidationScript for="com.mysite.command.test.testCommand" not="timeZone, field1" />

    ...
<body>
```

Any ideas why the js and css resources are not getting included?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the newer version of this plugin you must include

```
<r:require modules="jquery-validation-ui-qtip"/>
```

instead of

```
<r:require modules="jquery-validation-ui"/>
```

as you saw in that file.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I was trying to use the JQueryUI library. Try the script in the format given below. You can look at my original issue here [Issue that I faced when using jqueryui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14433710/grailsjquery-ui-integration-issue/14493602#14493602)

```
<head>

    <title>Simple GSP page</title>
    <g:javascript library="jquery" />
    <g:javascript library="jquery—validation-ui"/>
<r:layoutResources/>

    <script type="text/javascript">
     ….your scripts
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    ...
    <jqvalui:renderValidationScript for="com.mysite.command.test.testCommand" not="timeZone, field1" />

    <r:layoutResources/>
 ...
<body>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to <r:require module="jquery-validation-ui-qtip" /> as already stated, you also need the renderValidationScript tag itself to have qtip="true":

<jqvalui:renderValidationScript  for="com.mysite.command.test.testCommand" qtip="true"/>